# how to compare two data frames with different tolerance values for different columns?

Tags: r, compare, multiple-columns

There are two data frames like:

first data frame:

```
 d1       d2      d3
694   1.809509    74.9223
695   1.809510    73.2323
696   1.809511    23.7266
2243  1.465000    64.7542
2244  1.465001    85.7634
2651  1.143814    98.6344
2652  1.143813    46.9485
```

second data frame:

```
  d1       d2     d3
694    1.809509   73.5324
2243   1.465000   72.7854
2652   1.143813   25.4734
2784   1.162545   61.3456
2924   1.989442   88.9845
2846   1.929882   96.3874
```

I want to compare these two data frames. I tried with single a tolerance level in `all.equal()` method on both frames. but the requirement is different columns have different tolerance value. for example, tolerance of d1 is `3` or `40%`,  tolerance value for d3 is `2` or `30%` and for d2 '1' or `23%`. While the comparison it must pass under these tolerance values.

Help me in solving this problem. Every effort is appreciable.

Comment: Not sure that I understood what you need, but why not merge the dataframes?

Comment: Please post expected output. What do you mean *tolerance is 3*?

Comment: @DJV it's not related to merging of the data frames. it about passes the comparison test under some tolerance that means if in the first-row column  `d3` has value `74.9223` and `73.5324` in both frames, the tolerance value for this `d3` is `2`. so comparison must say these values are equal if they belong to `[74.9223 -2, 74.9223 +2]` or `[74.9223 - 30%, 74.9223 + 30%]`  (took 1st data frame as a base data frame and tolerance values must be applied on 1st 
 data frame).

Comment: @Sotos expected output is like below when tolerance value, say `d1`, `d2`, `d3` are `1%`, `1` and `3`:  `d1` value of  `1st` frame is `694` and with tolerance value `1%` its range is `[687.06, 700.94]` and if `d1` of  `2nd` frame have values in between the range `[687.06, 700.94]` then it should return values are equal both frames and this expected output sholud apply on all columns with respect to their tolerance value. at the end if everthing goes good according tvalues with tolerance values, it must say both farme are equal.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking for the identical function.  Identical test if two objects are the same.

```
x <- mtcars
y <- mtcars

identical( x, y )

y[ 3, 5] <- 300

identical( x, y )
```

You can loop the identical function for each column.

```
for( i in names( x ) ){
    print( identical( x[,i] , y[,i]) )
}
```

Also, in this case, where the rows and cols are in the same order - you can calculate the difference

```
z <- x - y
sapply( z , summary)
```

Comment: your solution sounds good but this one, I already implemented. Now I want to do a comparison with tolerance values as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

This function tests whether a column with the same name or in the same position is more or less than a specified threshold different.

```
x <- mtcars
y <- mtcars

y[ 3, 5] <- 300
y[ 2, 5] <- 4


y[ 3, 6] <- 2.8
y[ 2, 6] <- 4



test <-function( Z , TOL ){ as.numeric( 
    x[ , Z] > ( y[ , Z] * (1+TOL)) | 
    x[ , Z] < ( y[ , Z] * (1-TOL)) 
    )
    }


#compare the whole dataset at 20%
do.call( cbind, lapply( names( x )  , test , .2 ) )

# compare a specific column at 20 and 40 % difference
x$morethan20 <-  test( "drat" , .2 )
x$morethan40 <-  test( "wt" , .4 )
```